# the unpaid number of days is not computed in the employee payslips in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

i created a salary rule called Unpaid leave and it depends on a python code
 like this:

result= worked_days.Unpaid and worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days*(contract.wage/31) or 0

and the employee took 2 days unpaid leaves

i added the rule to the salay structure of the employee

then in the payslips i compute sheet and show the salary computation tab but the Unpaid leave show as zero inspite of the 2 days leave of that emplayee

is the unpaid number of days is zero? 
and if not zero why it is not computed in the employee payslip?

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is found from [here](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/hr-unpaid-leaves-payroll-management-in-odoo-10) and which is very described.
Here defined the payroll, rules, calculations, Unpaid deductions.